# Is it possible to make offset/shift in d3.js scales?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to make an "overflow" scale that will reset value and continue count from zero if it overflows limit

For example, I want to draw a chart but change the original 0 point place. The first column represents a normal scale, and in the second column I shifted the scale

```
5   2
4   1
3   0
2   5
1   4
0   3
```

I think I can alter input data and convert first half of values to negative so the domain will look like this [-2: 3]. But I would prefer not to alter input data values and just have a parameter in scale that can do this for me.

[image]

UPD:

I've tried to use more than 2 domain/range values - didn't give me the results that I want, so I wrote a custom interpolation function.
I doubt that only I need something like this and probably d3.js provide something similar. If you know a function like this in standard d3.js distribution please point me to it.

```js
 const svg = d3.select("svg").attr('height', 200);

myinterpolate = function(a, b) {
    var a = a;
    var b = b;
    var shift = 100;
    var max_value = Math.max(a, b)
    var min_value = Math.min(a, b)
    
    return function(t) {

        let result = a * (1 - t) + b * t + shift;
        if (result < min_value) {
            result = result + max_value
        } else if (result > max_value) {
            result = result % max_value
        }

        return result
    }
    ;
}

const myScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([200, 0]).interpolate(myinterpolate);
const axis = d3.axisLeft(myScale).tickValues(d3.range(10)).tickFormat(d=>~~d)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50,0)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg><svg>
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing... Can you provide an illustration (image) of the desired chart?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I know that y axis looks weird but my data match it and I want to have the filled area in the middle of the chart instead of splitting.

I know I can introduce negative numbers, but I don't want to alter original data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A custom interpolation function worked for me.
My code snippet uses a hardcoded value for the shift, but it can be rewritten to use shift value as a parameter.

```js
 const svg = d3.select("svg").attr('height', 200);

myinterpolate = function(a, b) {
    var a = a;
    var b = b;
    var shift = 100;
    var max_value = Math.max(a, b)
    var min_value = Math.min(a, b)
    
    return function(t) {

        let result = a * (1 - t) + b * t + shift;
        if (result < min_value) {
            result = result + max_value
        } else if (result > max_value) {
            result = result % max_value
        }

        return result
    }
    ;
}

const myScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([200, 0]).interpolate(myinterpolate);
const axis = d3.axisLeft(myScale).tickValues(d3.range(10)).tickFormat(d=>~~d)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50,0)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg><svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You said *"I would prefer not to alter input data values and just have a parameter in scale that can do this for me"*, but that's a very specific and highly unusual use case, so there is none.

What you could easily do is creating a piecewise scale with more than 2 domain/range values:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const myScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 3, 4, 6])
  .range([75, 6, 144, 98]);
const axis = d3.axisLeft(myScale).tickValues(d3.range(7)).tickFormat(d => ~~d)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50,0)"))
```

```css
path {
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

This simply answers your question *as it is*. Mind you that it raises several other questions: where are you drawing the values between 3 and 4? What's the meaning of the area between 6 and 0?

Comment: That last call passing in the appended `<g>` was mean ;-) Especially, as it requires you to scroll sideways to see what actually happens. Reminds me of the question where Mark, you and myself went to create the most obfuscated solution possible. Good ol' times.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.
I am trying to represent values that work like an angle, or a time - the maximum value of an angle is 360, after that it switched back to 0. Or in a time case after 23:59:59 next value will be 0. The values in my dataset lay around 0 or 23:59:59, or 0 and 360. So I want to shift axis that represents 0 to the middle of chart so there will be no gap between 23:59:59 and 0  and an observer will no need to use imagination to glue the bottom and top part of the chart together.